# How to post a string and an image using facebook api for ios

Tags: ios, facebook

i have a ui image and a nsstring .How do i post it to the the wall of a user using fb api for ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upload an image somewhere, in order to obtain an image url. once you have the url, you can post it something like:

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"feed" 
  andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: FEED_MESSAGE, @"message", 
        IMAGE_URL, @"picture", 
        LINK, @"link",
        name, @"name",
        description, @"description", nil]
   andHttpMethod:@"POST"
   andDelegate:self];
```

Note that the "picture" key is the actual url of the image, whereas "link" key is the url opened when an image is clicked.